# <s:url> namespace attribute in Struts2

Tags: jsp, url, struts2, struts-tags

**My Code is:**

```xml
<s:url action="work-items_input" includeParams="get" var="wiLink"  namespace="">
    <s:param name="workItemVO.workItemId" value="'5'"></s:param>
</s:url>    
<s:a action="%{wiLink}" namespace="/myaccount"><s:property value="subject"/></s:a>
```

In my application's ContextRoot is "pmp". Here above  is generating link as

> **/pmp//pmp**/myaccount/work-items_input.action?ajaxRequest=true&workItemVO.workItemId=5

above we can see context path is coming twice. **/pmp//pmp...** this is wrong. How to remove one extra context path?

Comment: Use <s:a> `href` with <s:url>.

Comment: @rj4u: Please stop adding [java-ee] tag as long as you haven't read its tag description nor know anything about Java EE. Moreover, stop at all with harvesting reputation by abusing the suggested edit system and triggering the completely broken review system of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the action and namespace attributes from the `<s:a>` tag, and use instead the `<s:url>`'s one with the `href` attribute:

```xml
<s:url action="work-items_input" includeParams="get" var="wiLink"  namespace="/myaccount">
    <s:param name="workItemVO.workItemId" value="'5'"></s:param>
</s:url>    
<s:a href="%{wiLink}"><s:property value="subject"/></s:a>
```

That should be enough.

Comment: No Now, it is `/pmp/main//pmp/myaccount/work-items_input.action?ajaxRequest=true&amp;workItemVO.workItemId=5"`. Here main is the namespace of current jsp file

Comment: @AleksandrM is right, I didn't noticed you used action instead of href. I've edited, try now

Comment: Yeah. You are right. I didn't notice href. Thanks It worked

Answer (score 0):

Above Accepted answer is absolutely correct, no doubt. But we can use `"includeContext="false"` also in `<s:url>` as an alternate with **action** attribute instead **href**.

```
<s:url action="work-items_input" includeParams="get" var="wiLink"  namespace="/myaccount" includeContext="false">
    <s:param name="workItemVO.workItemId" value="'5'"></s:param>
</s:url>    
<s:a action="%{wiLink}" namespace=""><s:property value="subject"/></s:a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because of the & so you must replace all occurrences to &.

```
<td align="right">
   <s:url action="collectionSummary" var="csUrl">  
    <s:param name="collectionSummary.name">
        <s:property value="debtCase.origNameTxt"/></s:param>
    <s:param name="socSecNum">
        <s:property value="debtCase.socSecNum"/></s:param>
    <s:param name="debtCaseId"><s:property value="debtCase.ID"/></s:param>
    <s:param name="nomenu">Y</s:param>
   </s:url>
   <s:a    href="#" 
           onclick="window.open(clearURL('%{csUrl}'));" <------- 
           title="View Collection Summary" 
           class="screen_link">
   <s:text name="link.CollSumm"/></s:a>
</td>


function clearURL(element){
    return element.replace(new RegExp('&amp;', 'g'),"&");
}
```